# Teams Tab App cannot be loaded when httpHeaderSecurity enabled in tomcat web.xml

Tags: microsoft-teams, hsts

We have a Teams Tab App and its web service provided through a Tomcat server. To enable httpHeaderSecurity, I enabled following part in Tomcat 9 web.xml and restarted tomcat. After that, the web service itself can be accessed through any browsers directly without any issue. But in Teams, the tab app can't be loaded.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
       <param-name>hstsMaxAgeSeconds</param-name>
       <param-value>31536000</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

After tried several times, I found that the issue is caused by the "filter-mapping" part, not the "filter" part. Does anyone have this issue before and what's the solution to fix it? Any clues will be appreciated.
[image: Strict-Transport-Security is correctly shown in response headers but app can't be loaded in Team./]

Answer (score 0):

Issue was resolved. The following params needs to be added into the httpHeaderSecurity filter. By these params, our app can be accessed from the iFrame of Teams as Teams is using an iFrame to load a tab app.

```
    <init-param>
       <param-name>antiClickJackingOption</param-name>
       <param-value>ALLOW-FROM</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
       <param-name>antiClickJackingUri</param-name>
       <param-value>https://teams.microsoft.com/</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

Comment: `ALLOW-FROM` is no longer supported as a directive for the `X-Frame-Options` header. Besides, it has nothing to do with HSTS.